# Unable to install VirtualBox guest additions on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with HWE -why?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, hardware-enablement-stack

### VirtualBox guest tools, a Recurring problem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

```
$ head -n2 /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20200203.1)]/ bionic main restricted

$ hwe-support-status
Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until april 2023.

$ dpkg -l | grep hwe
ii  linux-generic-hwe-18.04                    5.3.0.40.97                                      amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04            5.3.0.40.97                                      amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04              5.3.0.40.97                                      amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04                2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1            amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04                     1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3                          amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04           1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3                          amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04      0.28.1-1~18.04.1                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04         1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04              2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1            amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04           1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3                          amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04        19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                          amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04           1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04         1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04         2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1          amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04       1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1                               amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04           0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1                            amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04        1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04          1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1                                amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04        1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1                         amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver

$ uname -r
5.3.0-40-generic

$ sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
                        Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe : Depends: virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe (= 5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What gives `sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe  virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe`

Comment: @nobody that seems workable ... thnx